# Magento MagMI Value Replacer for image header issues

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I am trying to make a CSV template for mass import and would like it to be as clean as possible. I'm using Magento 1.9 with the Value Replacer v0.0.8a plugin in MagMI I hoped to use the same value across 3 headers without having to copy it in the CSV.

Specifically the "image" header cloned to "small_image" and "thumbnail".

I've tried:

```
Replaced attributes: small_image,thumbnail

small_image: {{ '{item.small_image}' == '' ? '{item.image}' : '{item.small_image}'}}
thumbnail: {{ '{item.thumbnail}' == '' ? '{item.image}' : '{item.thumbnail}'}}
```

Using this method seems to work but Image attributes processor (1.0.31) cant find the images for the 2 new columns. If I disable Value Replacer I can enter the columns manually and confirm it works for all 3 pictures.

Here is the sample CSV:

```
"sku","store","attribute_set","type","name","price","qty","is_in_stock","visibility","image","weight","categories","tax_class_id","supplier","manufacturer","kit_type","special_order","battery_capacity","battery_voltage","battery_type","featured"
"12333444","admin","Default","simple","t-shirt","2.95","1","1","4","/test.jpg","0.01","shirts","2","Great Planes","Traxxas","RTR","0","3200","11.1V","",""
"2222","admin","Batteries","simple","11.1v 2600MaH","29.95","1","1","4","11_1v_2600mah.jpg","1","Batteries/3s","2","Great Planes","Tenergy","","","2600","11.1v","lipo",""
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the small_image & thumbnail columns are not present in your csv.

so the test {item.small_image}=='' cannot be done and will probably issue a warning but also will not be true.

the following formulas will work better:

```
small_image : {{ (isset({item.small_image}) && !empty({item.small_image})?{item.small_image}:{item.image} }}
thumbnail : {{ (isset({item.thumbnail}) && !empty({item.thumbnail})?{item.thumbnail}:{item.image} }}
```

You can see i don't use any quotes, since {item.xxx} will be used as php variables ($item['xxx']).